# Cisco: prevent vlan's of communicating with eachother on cisco router (ACL alternative)

Tags: cisco, routing, security, acl, cisco-commands

Setup: Cisco router with multiple VLAN's configured on it.

How can you prevent 2 VLAN's communicating with eachother? Normally I would do this with ACL's like this:

```
access-list 102 deny ip 1.1.1.0 0.0.0.255 2.2.2.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 102 deny ip 2.2.2.0 0.0.0.255 1.1.1.0 0.0.0.255

int vlan 1
ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
access-group 102 in

int vlan 2
ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
access-group 102 in
```

This however is not handy when dealing with lot's of VLAN's configured on a router. Any suggestions of tweaking this or using an alternative to improve scalability?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fully agreed with Stefan. VRF is the way to go here. Quick example how to incorporate it to suggested config:

```
ip vrf VLAN1
  rd 42:1
ip vrf VLAN2
  rd 42:2
!
int vlan1
  ip vrf forwarding VLAN1
  ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
int vlan2
  ip vrf forwading VLAN2
  ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
!
```

Now vlan1 and vlan2 routing is separated.

To inspect routing tables, ping, traceroute you need to specify the vrf. e.g.:

- ip route vrf VLAN1
- traceroute vrf VLAN2 192.0.2.1
- ping vrf VLAN2 192.0.2.1

Or same in new AFI aware, IPv6 supporting config:

```
vrf definition VLAN1
  rd 42:1
  address-family ipv4
vrf definition VLAN2
  rd 42:2
  address-family ipv4
!
int vlan1
  vrf definition VLAN1
  ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
int vlan2
  vrf definition VLAN2
  ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.0
!
```

Answer (score 9):

While ACLs are a simple and safe way, it doesn't scale well indeed.

If your router provides VRF or at least the the VRF Lite feature you could group VLANs into VRFs. A [VRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Routing_and_Forwarding) can be seen like a virtual router, VRF instances cannot talk to each other unless you explicitely define routing between them.

In a complex network, I group VLANs into several security domains done with VRFs, such as a VRF for office clients and server, a VRF for tech devices (door access control, lifts, cctv, ...), a VRF for guests and visitors.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable routing between any VLAN, just use:

```
 Switch(config)# no ip routing
```

You will need another L3 device(router, multi-layer switch) to route between some VLANs.

Comment: I am assuming he still wants certain vlans to communicate with one another. Disabling routing kinda defies the point of having a router in the first place, he could just stick with his L2 switch where VLANs are already separated.

Comment: True, but then again, it's good to know there is an option :)